# Kendo & Aurelia: jQuery(...).kendoPager is not a function

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to get Kendo working in Aurelia and it is not going too easy...

The following call inside the VM attached() hook throws a "jQuery(...).kendoPager is not a function" exception in shim.min.js:1444:

```
jQuery("#pager").kendoPager({
  dataSource: dataSource
});
```

I've experimented with a number of ways to define the GlobalBehavior.jQueryPlugins() setting with the following being my best attempt thus far in main.js:

```
import {GlobalBehavior} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';
GlobalBehavior.jQueryPlugins["kendopager"] = "kendoPager";
```

Unfortunately there is not much documentation about this so one is prodding in the dark a bit so any help will be appreciated.

Normal jQuery functions work fine here so the problem does appear to be related to using Kendo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed the plugin with `jspm` ?

Comment: Well I hadn't actually as I was following the kendo-spike2 example done by one of the Aurelia team members where Kendo was simply included in the index.html file.

I have now done "jspm install kendo-ui" which executed successfully... but the error remains. I guess I need to add appropriate import statements now to include kendo - I just need to figure out how to do that...

Comment: I've written a blog about creating custom elements for wrapping css frameworks here: http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed dependency with JSPM, but you also need to import it in your VM class file. Put this import statement at the top of the file:

```
import {kendoUi} from 'kendo-ui';
```

After that you will be able to use in `attached` hook:

```
jQuery("#pager").kendoPager({
  dataSource: dataSource
});
```

Just one note, it's better not to refer to DOM elements but hardcoded selectors. You would better create a reference to element in template

```
<div ref="pager"></div>
```

and then in view-model have

```
jQuery(this.pager).kendoPager({
  dataSource: dataSource
});
```

Comment: Is there some place to see an example of this working? I'm struggling with a similar plugin (selectize.js).

Comment: http://blog.durandal.io/2015/04/24/aurelia-custom-elements-and-content-selectors/ to see jQuery and attached method in action

Comment: selectize hello world gist https://gist.github.com/monkeyhouse/fc5bd63ec852bad6b5e3